# How do I set different background images for different monitors in Gnome 3.10?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, fedora, gnome, xorg

How do I set different background images for different monitors in Gnome 3.10?

As one monitor is 1360x768 and another is 1920x1080 it is not possible to use the Span feature and keep proper aspect ratio (i.e. joining 2 images and tell gnome-tweak-tool to span it across the 2 monitors)

I am looking for a way so that I can set 1 image to be the background for one monitor.

A different image as the background for the second monitor.

I am using Fedora 20.

Comment: Please see if this link will help [https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=98610]

Comment: @Prasanna Span doesn't work properly as the image needs to be scaled to each monitor's resolution.

Comment: Did you try Compiz plugin suggestion from the above link?

Comment: @Prasanna [user@localhost ~]$ compiz 
compiz (core) - Error: Screen 0 on display ":0" already has a window manager; try using the --replace option to replace the current window manager.
compiz (core) - Fatal: No manageable screens found on display :0

Comment: @Prasanna Compiz is not compatible with Gnome Shell 3.10